# How to make voronoi move like living ants?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, animation-nodes, opengl

In Twitter link below, I saw this work by Joe Gatling a few days ago. His voronoi moves like live bugs. How do you create that in Blender?

[Moving ants with voronoi.](https://twitter.com/joegatling/status/1200145991426424833)

Edit. I'm back. I've just awhile ago asked a below question elsewhere in Stackoverflow. I was looking for scripts. In seconds, someone suggested wobbling the points with UV coordinates: u = time and v = sin; and using x, y of points with a sin wave. Now how do you do that?

[Stackoverflow: How to make voronoi move like live ants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173925/how-to-make-voronoi-move-like-live-ants/59174106#59174106)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think the Blender Voronoi has access to quite the same parameter as the one illustrated. Typical shader-Voronoi is based on the distances between randomly placed points, one to a cell, in a regular grid of rectangular cells. I think the specific 'wobble' effect you show is based on smoothly varying the positions of those points within the cells, *without moving the cells*.

Close enough, for this effect, might be to use the frame number to drive the Z component of 3D Voronoi, pushing the texture through our 2D XY slice. (The 'Flicker' path in the tree below.)

To drive a value in a shader node by frame number, just type `#frame` into the relevant field.

Having started, I couldn't resist following the rest of the instructions in your link:

[image]

With this sort of result:

[image]

I don't think it would be impossible to roll-your-own Voronoi, to give access to the noise generating the per-cell points.. or maybe there's a better way.

[image]

Comment: You are a wonder. My sincere thanks. :)