# I want to make a nasty wriggling worms procedural shader

Tags: animation, node-editor, procedural, mathematics

I saw a tutorial to make a spaghetti shader in substance designer, and in that they used some default noise texture that they altered to look like noodles. I want to do something similar in blender, whether it be spaghetti or nasty worms like in the title.

Is there a way to make these kind of shapes procedurally:
[image]

Or does anyone have any tips or ideas to help make a noodley wormy shader.

Comment: Do you mean this https://youtu.be/cNLKn-rUyvg?t=19 ?

Comment: I once asked in a old thread on how to make moving ants with voronoi. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159917/how-to-make-voronoi-move-like-living-ants   

Initially, I was inspired by work by Joe Gratling. You might get some ideas from him. 
https://mobile.twitter.com/joegatling/status/1200145991426424833

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with a *Musgrave texture.*
Set it to Ridged Multifractal and you'll get some nice creepy worms :)

[image]

Comment: That is so cool. I had missed this previously, when I was looking for something like this. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you like it :). I think it's a fairly recent update of the Musgrave texture