# Create a pattern of speckle/interference?

Tags: texturing, shaders

I am learning blender for scientific figures. I would like to create an image like this:

[image: Pattern Speckle]

Right now I have done this:

[image: nodes]

and the result is:

[image]

Do you know how can I improve it?

Comment: I think a great way to learn would be to represent and overlap multiple waves to show the interference? Though I imagine complex patterns like that emerge after many bounces of waves, so maybe geonodes could be useful here.

Comment: Possibly related: [Nasty wriggling worms procedural shader)(https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211759/78972)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd try is mixing different types of noise into the coordinate field.

A couple of interesting results:

[image]

[image]